# Image Upload Using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

This code does not print the temporary name of the uploaded image as well does not upload any picture in my Photo folder. but print image name. it work others computer correctly . where is the problem? please help me. i am using php  Version 5.6.20

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{

  $destination = "Photo/".$_FILES['image']['name'];
   $filename    = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];   
  echo $destination; 
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $filename;   
  echo "<br/>";

  if (file_exists($destination))

 echo "Sorry, file already exists.";

 else
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination);
  $name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
  $tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

  echo $tmp_name;
}


?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table>

<tr>
   <td>Choose Image</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="image"/> </td>
</tr> 

<tr>
   <td>Description:</td>
   <td><textarea name="Description" rows="4" cols="40"/></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
   <td></td>

    <td> <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Submit"></td>
</tr> 
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit_image'])) 
{

  $destination = "Photo/".$_FILES['image']['name'];
   $filename    = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];   
  echo $destination; 
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $filename;   
  echo "<br/>";

  if (file_exists($destination))

 echo "Sorry, file already exists.";

 else
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination);
  $name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
  $tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

  echo $tmp_name;
}


?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table>

<tr>
   <td>Choose Image</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="image"/> </td>
</tr> 

<tr>
   <td>Description:</td>
   <td><textarea name="Description" rows="4" cols="40"/></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
   <td></td>

    <td> <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Submit"></td>
</tr> 
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried this code it is working for me. please give read write permission of your photo folder
I think it will work for you.

Comment: what is the problem occur

Comment: in my code i print uploaded image name and temporary name of that image and upload that image in a folder name 'Photo'. but problem is it print only name of this image but not print temp_name and not upload any image in my photo folder

Comment: please give 777 permission on your photo folder

Comment: sorry, its not working. i told it work other computer but not work in my computer i don't know what is the problem. thank you for your answer and comment

Answer (score 1):

your code is working fine , check with 'Photo/' folder permission and tmp folder path too. ex : D:\xampp\tmp\phpDCD9.tmp.

Comment: try to put error_reporting(0); inside the script and check , what type of the error is getting

Comment: after print error_reporting(0) it showing output 22527. i don't understant this

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly working on my machine. I think you might want to check the directory name `Photo` to which the uploaded files are been stored. check your destination folder name inn your coding and defined folder name where your project is present are same. 
Kindly post your `error` or `warning` message so that it is easy to help.

Comment: i think everything is ok. i told that it work other computer but not working my computer. shit

Answer (score 0):

i think this part write properly like this it will solve

```
if (file_exists($destination)){
 echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
 }else{
    move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination);
  $name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
  $tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  echo $tmp_name;
}
```

Comment: done but not working, i don't know why its not printing temp_name in my computer. but it works other computer

Comment: not working it dosent mean you give wrong review to my question like that nobody will answer

Comment: dear i am not give that wrong review. you are trying to solve my problem why i give your comment wrong review?

Comment: some one give negative rank to my comment